# MS SQL Server - logon EVENTDATA - successful logins

Tags: sql-server

I want to ask if I am able to extract from logon EVENTDATA xml successful login events?

Why? Because somebody is trying to compromise our SQL Server and we are trying to extract IP addresses to be blocked.

Comment: Have you looked at a login trigger? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx

Comment: If your SQL Server is exposed to the public internet, blocking specific IP addresses will be endless. Use a whitelist in that case.

Comment: Dan Guzman, I developed logon trigger, however I am not able to get the info if the login was successful or not from the eventdata xml.

Comment: In the future we will have the VPN to our server. But now we have to somehow defend ourselfs. We don't know if all devs have static IP.

Comment: Are you using Enterprise or Developer Edition?

Comment: Express Edition 2014, I would like to avoid parsing the logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133221/discussion-between-bartosz-siemasz-and-dan-guzman).

Comment: Maybe there is a way to catch the logon failed error in the logon trigger on all server

Answer (score 0):

I managed to help myself. I created the extended events session for the login event and started collecting data. Next I looked for the attribute of a record which stores error number when logon fails - err num 18456 - I can't remind the name of the attribute. Thanks to that I was able to find the IP addresses that where used to compromise my server. Finally I created a rule on the firewall where I blocked founded IP addresses. Attacks have stopped.